# Invalid memory access with Fortran 77 subroutine

Tags: arrays, memory, fortran, fortran90, fortran77

Interacting with a fortran 77 subroutine results in an "Invalid memory access" error with code which I have summarised below:

```
subroutine mysub1()
    parameter :: kk=22
    real, dimension(KK) :: A
    call F77SUB(A)
end

subroutine mysub2()
    parameter, integer :: kk=22
    real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: A
    integer :: jj

    jj = 12
    allocate(A(kk,jj))

    call F77SUB(A(:,1)) ! ERROR: Invalid memory access
end
```

Where F77SUB is the fortran subroutine I am trying to use, which takes a 1D array and writes to it. In the above code, `mysub1` works but `mysub2` does not.

Can anyone suggest what the problem is above, or provide details on how array arguments are actually passed between F90 and F77 subroutines? I've seen instances of scalars being passed to F77 subroutines which apparently just take the memory address of the scalar to be the beginning of an array. Any enlightenment would be appreciated.

Comment: you can edit your question to fix that rather than commenting.  Also, is `jj` used before allocation?  if not, what is it?  What is the interface for `F77SUB` and how is dummy variable `A` declared within that function (assuming function because `CALL` is not present')

Comment: are you certain  `F77SUB` doesn't access the array (or anything else) out of bounds?

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, but not quite an answer ..

The code you have posted is crazee, and trying to fix a summarised code is a fruitless task so I won't spend long on it.  Here are a couple of egregious errors, please don't respond by telling us that in your 'real' code the errors are absent.

1. `F77SUB(A(:,1))` is syntactically wrong for calling a subroutine, `call F77SUB(A(:,1))` is correct.
2. Allocating an array which is not declared to be allocatable is not to be recommended.
3. Giving procedure arguments an explicit `intent` is greatly to be recommended.
4. The dichotomy you draw between Fortran 90 and FORTRAN77 routines is misleading.  If your compiler can compile Fortran 90 (and it must be able to or you wouldn't have any allocatables) then you are better off thinking of your code as just plain Fortran.

Comment: I have fixed the syntax errors you mentioned (1&2). #3 doesn't make much sense to me since I don't have any procedure arguments in my procedures above. You haven't made any suggestion for what the actual problem might be.

Comment: You're still asking us to try to sort out the problems with a summarised version of the code.  Post a minimal, compilable example which reproduces the problem.  Probably best to include the code for `f77sub` in any updates you make.  Probably also best to include, by cut'n'paste the precise error message.  Probably also a good idea to re-compile and re-execute with array-bounds checking and subroutine argument checking switched on -- your compiler documentation will tell you how to do both.  Oh, and you only fixed the syntax for calling a subroutine once.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was declaring the 1D A to be double precision and the 2D A to be real. Somehow it let me pass them both to the F77 routine without complaint.

Comment: basically the bug was in a different version of the code from that shown in the question? You should either edit the question to reflect the error or delete the whole thing.  Of course a useful lesson learned here is no type checking is done on *external* subroutine calls.

Comment: "Of course a useful lesson learned here is no type checking is done on external subroutine calls" Thank you! This explains the problem. What counts as external? i.e. how can I enforce type checking?